# Firebase cloud messaging's remoteMessage has empty body

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging, android-push-notification

I am using Firebase cloud Messaging to show push notification but its not showing instead its not doing anything I have connected Firebase successfully with my application but now i am just Toasting the body of notification in onMessageRecieved

```
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This is my whole onMessageRecieved function but it is not toasting anything I have tried sending notification many times

Comment: from server in payload you sending content in "notification" or "data" key? if "data" then try "notification" and let me know.

Comment: yes, please post the payload you are sending from firebase side.